# Create a video from another video by taking some frames only but without writing them onto a file

Tags: python, opencv

I have a little weird problem here!

I have a video in a file. I want to extract some frames out of this video and make a video out of this and then use it to display( Note: I do not want to use imshow() for this ). And I want to do this without writing this into a file.

```
Algorithm:
1. Read the video from file
2. extract the frames
3. make a video out of these frames(save it as a variable; do not write it into a file)
4. Use this variable which holds the new video for displaying
```

Any suggestions would be of great help!

Comment: Suggestions: 1. `VideoCapture` 2.`<<` 3.`vector<cv::Mat>` 4.`imshow()`

Answer (score 1):

Create a `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_name)`. Get the width and height of your movie with

```
h = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
w = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
```

Create a numpy array

```
frames = np.zeros((h, w, 3, number_of_frames), np.uint8)
```

and save the frames you want to keep to this array:

```
error, frame = cap.read()
frames[:,:,:,i] = frame
```

If you don't know how many frames you have beforehand, just concatenate them in a Python list.

Then, display your frames.

Comment: the variable 'frames' would be a list of frames right ? will i be able to use it just like a video? I want to use it to display it in the form of a video player using a UI

Comment: If you need just the list of frames without intent to change the pixel data, you could indeed go with a Python list frames = [], and then frames.append(frame).

Comment: I don't know what you have in mind exactly with all of this, but keep in mind that video data will take a lot of memory. You can't put a whole (maybe even HD) movie into RAM.